# Poor performance to calculate distances with latitude and longitude

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get the quantity of people in 2km or less from specific locations, to do that I'm calculating distances with latitude and longitude. In one table I just have latitude, longitude and in other I have more fields but with latitude and longitude as well.

- Table1 = 488792 rows
- Table2 = 63003 rows

The query is valid and will process 12.3 MB when run.

The query I'm using is:

```
select 
e.lat,
e.long,
e.searches,
count(distinct l.id)
from dataset.table1 e
join dataset.table2 l 
     on 6371000*ACOS(COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) <= 2000 # way to calculate distance from lats and longs
group by e.lat,
e.long,
e.searches
```

But the query is not running, it takes more than 15 minutes every time and I have to cancel.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Full table scans is likely the issue. You need good indices in place and it looks like you have a very complicated join. Any or all of these things could be responsible.

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset? I would like to play on optimizing this query, but I need a suitable test bed

Comment: Sure @FelipeHoffa, how can I send you? Thanks!

Comment: https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/761635507080081408

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, I share there. buoyant-history-159518:test_lat_long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query, similar to your original one, takes 2 minutes:

```
SELECT distance, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT
  e.lat,
  e.long
  , 6371000*ACOS(COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) <= 2000 distance
  , e.long-l.long longlong, e.lat-l.lat latlat
FROM
  `buoyant-history-159518.test_lat_long.table1` e
JOIN
  `buoyant-history-159518.test_lat_long.table1` l
ON 
 (COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) <= COS(2000/6371000) + 4.5E-8
)
GROUP BY distance
```

To prevent floating point errors, I had to transform the JOIN inequality:

```
6371000*ACOS(COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) 
<= 2000
```

to the similar:

```
(COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) <= COS(2000/6371000) + 4.5E-8)
<= COS(2000/6371000) + 4.5E-8
```

Now the question is how can we get a much better performance than 2 minutes? Let's add to the JOIN some 'sanity' filters -> No 2 points in the same area can have a distance between lats and long more than 0.something:

```
SELECT distance, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT
  e.lat,
  e.long
  , (COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) +SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-e.lat)) *SIN(3.14159265359/180*(90-l.lat)) *COS(3.14159265359/180*(e.long-l.long))) <= COS(2000/6371000) distance
  , e.long-l.long longlong, e.lat-l.lat latlat
FROM
  `buoyant-history-159518.test_lat_long.table1` e
JOIN
  `buoyant-history-159518.test_lat_long.table1` l
ON 
 NOT (e.long=l.long AND e.lat=l.lat) 
 AND ABS(e.long-l.long) < 0.021 #sanity JOIN check
 AND ABS(e.lat-l.lat) < 0.018 #sanity JOIN check
)
GROUP BY distance
```

With this we get very similar results, but in 12 seconds instead of 2 minutes.

I can't optimize your exact query, as your sample tables don't have the same number or rows nor columns - but trying applying those "sanity JOIN checks" before going for the full CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Felipe! I changed a little bit the query to met our needs in the production dataset, but your tricks made it possible to work!

Answer (score 2):

Doing this kind of brute force analysis using `JOIN` on predicate for distance is not going to have good performance. BigQuery team is looking into adding better support for geospatial analysis (i.e. using `ST_DWithin` function in `JOIN` predicate). In the meantime, droping into Postgres and using PostGIS extension is probably your best bet.

Comment: As someone who is interested in geospatial analysis in BigQuery, how can I get updates about availability these features?